# Laravel - looking for view with 'http://localhost' in filename

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm getting an error on one of my views - 'View [http:..localhost:8000.bookings.create] not found.'
This view was originally working as bookings.index, but I realised I wanted to use that page to display existing bookings so I renamed the file to bookings/create.blade.php and updated the Controller and web.php to match. The index page now works, but the create file is 'missing.'

After reading similar problems on this site, I've cleared the cache with 'php artisan cache:clear', and I've tried restarting the server, but the problem remains.

Here's my code.

web.php

```
Route::resource('bookings', BookingController::class)
    ->only(['index', 'store', 'create', 'edit', 'update', 'destroy'])
    ->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
```

BookingController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Model\User;
use App\Models\Booking;
use App\Models\Field;
use App\Models\Timeslot;
use Carbon\CarbonPeriod;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class BookingController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'date'    => 'required|date|after:yesterday',
        ]);

        return view('bookings.index', [
            'fields' => Field::get(),
            'timeslots' => Timeslot::get(),
            'date' => $request->date,
            'bookings' => Booking::where('date', $request->date)->get(),
        ]);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view(route('bookings.create', [
            'fields' => Field::get(),
            'timeslots' => Timeslot::get(),
        ]));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'start'    => 'required|date|after:yesterday',
            'end'      => 'required|date|after:start',
            'field'    => 'required|array',
            'timeslot' => 'required|array',
        ]);

        // create Models
        $start = $request->start;
        $end   = $request->end;
        $period= CarbonPeriod::create($start, $end);
        // dd($period);
        $data = array();
        foreach ($period as $date) {
            foreach ($request->field as $f) {
                foreach ($request->timeslot as $ts) {
                    $booking = Booking::firstOrCreate([
                        'date'        => $date->format('Y-m-d'),
                        'field_id'    => $f,
                        'timeslot_id' => $ts,
                    ]);
                }
            }
        }
        Booking::insert($data);

        return redirect(route('bookings.create'));
    }
}
?>
```

resources/views/bookings/create.blade.php

```
<x-app-layout>
    <!-- Session Status -->
    <x-auth-session-status class="mb-4" :status="session('status')" />

    <div class="max-w-2xl mx-auto p-4 sm:p-6 lg:p-8">
        @if(auth()->user()->roles()->where('role', 'admin')->exists())
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('bookings.store') }}">
                @csrf

                <!-- Select Dates -->
                <div>
                    <x-input-label for="start" :value="__('Start Date')" />

                    <x-text-input id="start" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="date" name="start" :value="old('start')" required autofocus />

                    <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('start')" class="mt-2" />
                </div>

                <!-- End Time -->
                <div class="mt-4">
                    <x-input-label for="end" :value="__('End Date')" />

                    <x-text-input id="end" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="date" name="end" :value="old('end')" required />

                    <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('end')" class="mt-2" />
                </div>
                <div class="flex justify-between">
                    <div>
                    <x-input-label for="field[]" value="Field" />
                        @foreach ($fields as $field)
                            <input type="checkbox" name="field[]" id="" value="{{ $field->id }}" /> {{ $field->name }}<br />
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <x-input-label for="timeslot[]" value="Timeslot" />
                        @foreach ($timeslots as $timeslot)
                            <input type="checkbox" name="timeslot[]" value="{{ $timeslot->id }}" />{{ $timeslot->start }} - {{ $timeslot->end }}<br />
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <x-primary-button class="ml-3">
                        {{ __('Create Booking Slots') }}
                    </x-primary-button>
                </div>
            </form>
        @endif
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

One of the 'vendor frames' shown in the error page relates to this function in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php

```
protected function findInPaths($name, $paths)
{
    foreach ((array) $paths as $path) {
        foreach ($this->getPossibleViewFiles($name) as $file) {
            if ($this->files->exists($viewPath = $path.'/'.$file)) {
                return $viewPath;
            }
        }
    }

    throw new InvalidArgumentException("View [{$name}] not found.");
}
```

I added a line before the 'if' to display $path.'/'.$file and the problem becomes clearer. When I navigate to the root, it shows "/home/mag/code/soccer/resources/views/welcome.blade.php", but if I navigate to bookings/create, it shows "/home/mag/code/soccer/resources/views/http://localhost:8000/bookings/create.blade.php". Clearly the 'http://localhost:8000/' shouldn't be there, but I don't know where it's coming from or why it's not being stripped.

This function is called by public function find($name) in the same file, but from there I'm lost. Searching for 'FileViewFinder->find(' returns many instances in the log files, but not in the actual code.

Any advice on how to proceed is appreciated. Did I break something by renaming the file? I'm sure if I rebuilt this project in another directory, the problem wouldn't appear, but I'd rather know why this happened so I can fix it and avoid it happening again.

Comment: `return view(route('bookings.create', ...` ... The `route` helper returns an absolute URL to your route; that is not a path to a view file ... I would assume you just mean to use `'bookings.create'` as the view to use

Comment: That did it. How did I not see that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @lagbox said You dont need to use `route` while redirecting to view

```
public function create()
{
    return view('bookings.create', [
        'fields' => Field::get(),
        'timeslots' => Timeslot::get(),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: lagbox answered this first, but yes, this fixed my problem. Thanks.